# JQuery popup to buy tickets

Tags: jquery, html, popup

I'm actually working on a Web project and I need to do a popup with JQuery that allows the user to buy tickets for an event. I know how to do it with JavaScript but the company wants it in JQuery.

I've tried to use Dialog but I think that I'm not using it properly.

```
<div id="dialog" style='position:absolute; display:none; width:1000px; height:475px; left:50%; top:50%; margin-left: -660px; margin-top: -300px; z-index: 999999; background-color: white; border-radius:5%'>
        <?php require_once('entradas.php') ?>
    </div>
    <script src="<?php echo $url; ?>avuixdema/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });

        $( "#entrades" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
    </script>
```

As you can see the popup ignores the width that I've fixed in the HTML. Also the close button doesn't appear at the top of the popup.

[POPUP DIALOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezGm6.png)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try not to absolute position the dialog.

Comment: I need it to be absolute because it has to be placed in the middle of the screen and it has to ignore all the other elements position